# Rails app: Testing a redirect doesn't route to where it should in test but does in life

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I have set up my application so that if the use is logged in, it will skip the welcome page and redirect the user. This is done in the Welcome controller:

```
  def show
    if logged_in?
      redirect_to myrecipes_url
    else
      render template: "welcome/home"
    end
  end
```

I have written the following tests:

This one fails:

```
  test "login with valid information" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert_redirected_to myrecipes_url
  end
```

And I get the following error:

```
 FAIL["test_login_with_valid_information", UsersLoginTest, 1.4506160049932078]
 test_login_with_valid_information#UsersLoginTest (1.45s)
    Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/myrecipes> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/>.
    Expected "http://www.example.com/myrecipes" to be === "http://www.example.com/".
```

This test passes which is a similar test.

```
  test 'welcome page gets skipped when logged in' do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get root_path
    assert_redirected_to myrecipes_url
  end
```

This started occurring when in my controllers (account activation, password reset, sessions) the user should be logged in,  I decided to change the line of code:       redirect_to myrecipes_url to       redirect_to root_url

The reason being that that I wouldn't have to reprogram where the root was redirecting in each controller since that was handled when you routed to the root. However the tests don't seem to be picking up on this.

How do I get the tests to acknowledge the redirect without having to reprogram it into each controller?

Comment: have you got a `before_filter` or `before_action` in your controller that might be redirecting you to `root_url`?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn There is no before_filter or before_action in either my session controller (the /login one) or the welcome controller. There is one in recipes that checks if you'er logged in but it would send you to /login not the root.

Comment: Note also that this works when I do it manually. If I log in I get redirected to the /myrecipes page as expected.